# ¿Cómo puedo crear un método de suma de dos arreglos y obtener el tercer arreglo?

Tags: java

¿Y cómo llamar el método desde mi `main` en Java?

```
 static int vectorSuma[];

 static int[] suma(int vectorAA[],int vectorBB[],int vectorSuma[]){
     
     for (int i = 0; i < vectorAA.length; i++) {
         vectorSuma[i] = vectorAA[i];
         for (int j = 0; j < vectorBB.length; j++) {
             vectorSuma[i] = vectorBB[i]+ vectorAA[i];
         }
     }
     return vectorSuma;
 }
```

y en main lo llame .

```
int [] valorTotal = suma(vectorSuma);
         
System.out.print("\nsuma total : "+Arrays.toString(valorTotal));
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve], en tu caso particular, entradas y salidas ideales y la salida que te dá

Answer (score 0):

El codigo del programa que resuelve la pregunta es

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int a[] = {1,2,3};
        int b[] = {5,4,3,2,1};
        
        int result[];
        
        //Se invoca el metodo de la suma
        result = suma(a,b);
        
        System.out.println("*** Resultados ****");
        for(int idx=0;idx<result.length;idx++){
            System.out.println(result[idx]);
        }
        
    }
    
    //Implementacion del metodo para la suma
    private  static int[] suma(int vectorAA[],int vectorBB[]){
        
        //Determina cual vector es mas grande
        int lmax = vectorAA.length;
        int lmin = vectorAA.length;
        int vmax[] = vectorAA;
        if(vectorBB.length>lmax) {
            lmax=vectorBB.length;
            vmax=vectorBB;
        }
        if(vectorBB.length<lmin) lmin=vectorBB.length;
        

        //Suma los elementos
        int vectorSuma[] = new int[lmax];
        int idx=0;
        while(idx<lmin){
            vectorSuma[idx]=vectorAA[idx]+vectorBB[idx];
            idx++;
        }
        
        //Agrega los elementos que no tienen un par para sumar
        while(idx<lmax){
            vectorSuma[idx]=vmax[idx];
            idx++;
        }

        return vectorSuma;
     }

}
```

Comment: hermano gracias me resulto , esto igual funcionaria con las demas operaciones matematicas exactamente, pero cambiando algunas cosas?

Comment: Si te sirvió la solución deberías registrar la aceptación de la respuesta. Eso alienta a los miembros de la comunidad a contestar las preguntas.